# What is the latest version of BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK supported by Worklight 6.1.0.1?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am running Worklight 6.1.0.1 Studio on OS X Mavericks. I am trying to build for the BlackBerry 10 environment but I keep getting the error:   **WebWorks SDK source file was not found. Make sure to set it in application-decsriptor.xml: Replace it with path to WebWorks**

I made sure that WEBWORKS_HOME environment variable points to the correct location (even by removing the spaces in the folder name) but still get same error !!

Now, the error went away only after I downgraded from BB10WebWorksSDK2.0.0.71 to BB10WebWorksSDK1.0.4.11.

It is NOT CLEAR at all which version of BB10 SDK is supported just by looking at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838

Can somebody confirm that BB10WebWorksSDK2.0.0.71 is indeed NOT supported by Worklight 6.1.0.1  ?

Roque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Worklight supports WebWorks 1.0.4.11 (which [can be obtained from this location](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/)). 
IBM Worklight does not currently support WebWorks 2.x.

If you'd like to use WebWorks 2.x anyway, you can try following this blog post: [HowTo: Worklight 6.1.0.x BlackBerry 10 app with WebWorks SDK 2.0](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/worklight_blackberry10_project_with_webworks_sdk_2_0?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks Idan. Can you make sure the documentation guys make this  clear in  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838